# why i have to refresh/rewrite my code to make it work while trying to save the state for a specific user in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, use-effect, use-state, asyncstorage

I am trying to make a test sheet for user. If he passes the test, he is directed to a pass screen and even after totally closing the app, when that specific user comes back, the state is saved meaning, the passing screen still remains there. But for a new user, I want the app to run from start and show him test screen 1st and then act accordingly if he passes the test or not. My app is working fine but it keeps reacting according to the user that was previously logged in, until i refresh/rewrite any of the lines from code. Then it acts correctly according to the current user. Following is the code:

```
  import React ,{useState, useEffect} from "react";
import {View, Alert, Image, StyleSheet, Text, Modal, TouchableOpacity, TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native';
import Voice from 'react-native-voice';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';


import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
  const key = auth().currentUser.uid + "hasPassed"
  

export const hasPassed = async () => {
    return AsyncStorage.getItem(key).then(result => result != null ? JSON.parse(result) : undefined).catch(e => console.log(e))    
}

export const setHasPassed = async (newPassed) => {
    return AsyncStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify({hasPassed: newPassed})).catch(e => console.log(e))
}



export default alpht =({navigation}) => { 

 
  

  const [index, setind] = useState(0);
  const [idis, setidis] = useState(false);
  const [count, setcount] = useState(0);
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [results, setResults] = useState('');
  const [disb, setdis] = useState(true);
  const [ndisb, setndis] = useState(true);

 useEffect(() => {
   //Setting callbacks for the process status
   Voice.onSpeechStart = onSpeechStart;
   Voice.onSpeechEnd = onSpeechEnd;
   Voice.onSpeechResults = onSpeechResults;
   Voice.onSpeechError = onSpeechError;

   return () => {
    //destroy the process after switching the screen
    Voice.destroy().then(Voice.removeAllListeners);
   
    
  };
}, []);


const onSpeechStart = (e) => {
  //Invoked when .start() is called without error
  console.log('onSpeechStart: ', e);

};


const onSpeechEnd = (e) => {  
  console.log('onSpeechEnd: ', e);
 setdis(false);
 setndis(true);
 
    //Invoked when SpeechRecognizer stops recognition
    
  
  };

  const onSpeechError = (e) => {
    //Invoked when an error occurs.
    console.log('onSpeechError: ', e);
    setError(JSON.stringify(e.error));
  };

  

  const onSpeechResults = (e) => {
    //Invoked when any results are computed
    console.log('onSpeechResults: ', e);
   
    setResults(e.value);

    
  };


  const startRecognizing = async () => {
    //Starts listening for speech for a specific locale
    try {
      await Voice.start('tr-TURKEY');
      setError('');
     setResults('');
      
    } catch (e) {
      //eslint-disable-next-line
      console.error(e);
    }
  };

  


  const destroyRecognizer = async () => {
    //Destroys the current SpeechRecognizer instance
    try {
      await Voice.destroy();
      setError('');
     setResults('');
     setdis(true);

     if (index<7){
       setind(index+1);
       setndis(true);
       setidis(false);
       
     }
//  console.log(index);
//      if (index==6){
//      setndis(true);
//     }
    } catch (e) {
      //eslint-disable-next-line
      console.error(e);
    }
  };
function Check() {
  if (results.includes(words[index])){
 
    Alert.alert('Correct!','You are learning so well!');
    
     if(index==7) {
      if(count<=5)
      {
           
         setHasPassed(true).then(() => setshowpass(true))
          //setshowpass(true);
      }
      else{
        console.log(count)
        Alert.alert('fail','fail');
      }
    }
    if (index==7){
      setndis(true);
      setdis(true);
      setidis(true);
    }
    else{
   setndis(false);
   setdis(true);
   setidis(true);
    }
   
  }
  else{
    Alert.alert('Ops!','Looks like you went wrong somewhere. Try again!');
    setcount(count+1);
    
    setdis(true);
    setndis(true);
   
    if(count==5){
      Alert.alert('Restest', 'Looks like you had way too many mistakes!')
      setind(0);
      setcount(0);
      setdis(true);
    }
  }
}


  const words=['ceket', 'çilek', 'elma', 'fare', 'öğretmen', 'otobüs', 'şemsiye', 'uçak'];
  const [show, setshow]=useState('');
    const [showpass, setshowpass]=useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
     //console.log(auth().currentUser.uid);
        setshow(true);
      }, []);

      useEffect(() => {
        const getState = async () => {
          const result = await hasPassed()
          setshowpass(result ? result.hasPassed : false)
      }
      getState()
      // console.log(auth().currentUser.uid)
      //   if (showpass === false) {

           
      //     setshow(true)
      //     console.log('hey');
      //    // return null
      //   }
      }, []);

     
      console.log(auth().currentUser.uid)
      if (showpass === false) {

         
        // setshow(true)
        console.log('hey');
       return null
      }
        
return(
...
// all the other code here
)
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you cut your example code to the minimum relevant stuff - there's a lot to take in here and much of it is not related to the problem you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

I see code to store the result in AsyncStorage, and then, the first time the component mounts, it checks whether the result is true, and shows the screen.  If you're using fast refresh, and you update the code, the useEffect won't run again, since the screen has already mounted and you have an empty dependency array.

So, to me, it looks like you've built it to produce the behavior you've described. I don't see any code to log a user out or to clear AsyncStorage.  Maybe there is some mechanism you haven't shown to do that. If not, one way to accomplish this is in the return of the useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  ...
  return () => {
    setHasPassed(undefined).then(() => logOut());
    // not sure how you log out your user
```

You're already using this pattern in your top useEffect to destroy your speech recognizer.

Comment: my user is logging out in a separate auth.js file,the question here is , lets say i have user 1 and user 2 and user 1 is currently logged in, he passed the test and the app shows him passing screen and the state is saved. Now user 1 logs out and user 2 logs in, he is a completely new user he has never given test before but my app has still saved the state for the user 1 and keeps showing passing screen even to the user 2. This issue do get solve but only if i rewrite any of my lines in the code after i log in with the new user. why is it happening and how can i solve this issue??

Comment: Are you clearing the value in local storage when the user logs out?  Showing the logout code would help a lot